# Sort messages from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to create a multi user chatting app using PHP and JS. Here's my DB structure with some sample data of different users `msg_owner_id` and `msg_reciever` are IDs from the registered `users` table.
To distinguish the users, lets assume ID 20 is logged in and we want to only display chats he's sent and received.

| id | message | msg_owner_id | msg_reciever | msg_time | msg_type | seen | seen_time | note(not part of table) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hey | 20 | 6 | 10:42:51 | interchats | 0 |  | <----- 20 sent to 6 |
| 2 | hi | 6 | 20 | 10:43:20 | interchats | 0 |  | <------6 replied to 20 |
| 3 | am fine | 20 | 6 | 10:44:11 | interchats | 0 |  | <------20 sends to 6 again |
| 4 | mannnn | 11 | 20 | 10:53:02 | interchats | 0 |  | <------20 receives from 11 |

Can anyone help me with how to retrieve the messages showing only the most recent message per user if the sent is most recent let it show instead of the received the table isn't displaying the way I want it to hope you can read it.

Comment: Sorry @Ernest, your question not so clear, Please provide desired result.

Comment: Why did you tag "jquery"?

Comment: i use ajax (jquery) to display the messages without refreshing the page

Comment: @Slava i've tried fetching the messages but let's say the same id appears in the sent and recieved messages how can we merge them by the newest message to create a separate thread per user without duplicating the id's (names) displayed

Comment: @slava desired result is this 6 -> am fine 11 -> mannnn

Comment: If the result-set coming from the relational database (I assume you meant MySQL) is not sorted, how do you choose what rows to retrieve? Or there's just no pagination and you fetch the entire chat, no matter how lengthy? In any case, PHP has [usort()](https://www.php.net/usort) and JavaScript has [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), but the overall approach is strange.